# Unable to run my Grails app - how to fix this?

Tags: grails

When I run my Grails project in Eclipse then the following error comes. What is the meaning of the error? How to remove this? I am using the Git to share the application on Bitbucket. Why is it showing the list of the plugins? Also when I run the app from the command prompt of the Grails then the app runs and there are no errors. Why is this?

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.0
|Configuring classpath
Error |
G:\programming\TE\TE_intern_grails\local directory for grails using git\arpte\arpte does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
Error |
The following commands are supported outside of a project:
    add-proxy
    clear-proxy
    create-app
    create-multi-project-build
    create-plugin
    help
    install-app-templates
    list-plugins
    package-plugin
    plugin-info
    remove-proxy
    set-proxy
|Run 'grails help' for a complete list of available scripts.Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: It looks like Eclipse doesn't know where is your Grails installation

Comment: Download the grails tool suit and import your project

Comment: How to tell Eclipse where is my Grails installation?

Comment: It looks like Eclipse doesn't launch the run-app command from the grails project folder. This is why you get this message 'git\arpte\arpte does not appear to be part of a Grails application.'

Answer (score 2):

You could import the project as a Git project in eclipse and try to run. This has fixed my issue recently.

Otherwise

1. Right click on the project
2. Click on run
3. Go to Run As, then select Run Configurations
4. Delete the existing run configurations of the present project
5. Run the project now.

It will work perfectly.

Comment: @Pranav Shukla if the answer given above has solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly!